# sed command to grep between last slash and .jks

Tags: regex, sed

Sample text file contains multiple entries is as under-

```
$ant.cat/cat-dog.fox/ABC.DEF-GHI.JKL.jks
/mno.cat/cat-dog.fox/XYZ-RST.ABC.jks
```

expected output is-

```
ABC.DEF-GHI.JKL.jks
XYZ-RST.ABC.jks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `basename`

```
$echo "ant.cat/cat-dog.fox/ABC.DEF-GHI.JKL.jks" |xargs    basename
ABC.DEF-GHI.JKL.jks
```

using sed

```
$echo "ant.cat/cat-dog.fox/ABC.DEF-GHI.JKL.jks" | sed 's#.*\/##g'
ABC.DEF-GHI.JKL.jks
$
```